# How can I catch an exception in Kotlin coroutine when I am awaiting it in another function?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

Sorry for the vague title, couldn't come up with something better.

So I read [this](https://medium.com/@sampsonjoliver/promises-in-android-and-java-d6b1c418ea6c) article and wanted to do the same. problem is that I can't do `try { promise... } catch (e) { }` cause the error gets swallowed. I can catch the error where I await it, but I don't want that.

and my code looks like this:

```
typealias Promise<T> = Deferred<T>

fun <T, R> Promise<T>.then(handler: (T) -> R): Promise<R> = GlobalScope.async(Dispatchers.Main) {
    // using try/catch here works but I don't want it here.
    val result = this@then.await()
    handler.invoke(result)
}

object PromiseUtil {
    fun <T> promisify(block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T): Promise<T> = GlobalScope.async { block.invoke(this) }
}

// somewhere in my UI testing it.
try {
    PromiseUtil.promisify { throw Exception("some exp") }
        .then { Log.d("SOME_TAG", "Unreachable code.") }
} catch (e: Exception) {
    Log.d("ERROR_TAG", "It should catch the error here but it doesn't.")
}
```

And I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50707785/why-does-launch-swallow-exceptions-in-kotlin-coroutines) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783141/kotlin-coroutine-swallows-exception?rq=1) too, but I want to somehow catch errors in the UI code, and don't want to use `runBlocking { ... }`.

Thanks.

Comment: On your UI I think you should use the other extensions `thenAsync` for the `await()` to be done correctly.

Comment: @shkschneider tested that but it didn't work, and most of the time I don't have other asynchronous work to do after first one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception is never caught because it's never propagated by the `async` call. That happens when `await()` is called.

See [coroutine exception handling](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/exception-handling.html).

Your code should be:

```
// somewhere in my UI testing it.
try {
    PromiseUtil.promisify { throw Exception("some exp") }
        .then { Log.d("SOME_TAG", "Unreachable code.") }.await() // <--- added await() call
} catch (e: Exception) {
    Log.d("ERROR_TAG", "It should catch the error here but it doesn't.")
}
```

But this won't compile as `await()` is a suspending function. Therefore, it should be more like:

```
// somewhere in my UI testing it.
GlobalScope.launch(CoroutineExceptionHandler { coroutineContext, throwable ->
            Log.d("ERROR_TAG", "It will catch error here")
            throwable.printStackTrace()
        }) {
   PromiseUtil.promisify { throw Exception("some exp") }
        .then { Log.d("SOME_TAG", "Unreachable code.") }.await()
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought awaiting it in "then function" will do that.